# Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String' :AutoIncrement Customer ID

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, auto-increment

I have a table named customer where I have two columns named as cust_ID and Temp_ID. Temp_ID is an integer. I wan to a concatenated ID as cust_ID.

I have following function to get maximum of temp_id and to increment it by 1.

```
Private Function Tempo()

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = ("Select MAX(Temp_ID) From Customer")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim sqlRead As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Temp1 = sqlRead.Item("Temp_ID")
        Temp1 = Temp1 + 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

and I have click event for customer id textbox in the vb.net customer interface.

```
 Private Sub txtBoxCustProfileID_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBoxCustProfileID.Click
    Tempo()
    Dim x = Temp1
    Dim newID = String.Concat("C/", cmbNationality.Text, "/", Now.Year, "/", x)
    txtBoxCustProfileID.Text = newID
End Sub
```

When i run this code I get following error message in Tempo function as "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String' " I really don't understand what this means and I am new to programming also.
Please help.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict; an ID that *your code* increments is not an AutoIncrement ID. Gluing 6 bits of information together for an ID is bad design.  Get rid of the Try/Catch and you'd at least know which line is causing the error

Comment: @Farhan Anam : Temp1 = sqlRead.Item("Temp_ID") line

Answer (score 0):

You currently aren't getting a column named Temp_ID from your sql query.

You need to change this:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("Select MAX(Temp_ID) From Customer")
```

To this:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("Select MAX(Temp_ID) AS Temp_ID From Customer")
```

Also get rid of this line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```